perplexity very high on wikitext for GPT2XL
I am trying to compute the perplexity of pretrained GPT2XL model on wikitext dataset, but I am getting a very high value (ppl=25353.77267945427), and I do not understand why it is that high. Here is the code:
import torch
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
from datasets import load_dataset
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
import math

dataset = load_dataset("wikitext", "wikitext-2-raw-v1", split="test")
gpt2_tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("gpt2-xl")
gpt2_tokenizer.pad_token = gpt2_tokenizer.eos_token
gpt2_model = AutoModelForCausalLM.from_pretrained("gpt2-xl").to("mps")

all_texts = [example['text'] for example in dataset]
inputs = gpt2_tokenizer(
    all_texts,
    return_tensors='pt',
    padding=True,
    truncation=True,
    max_length=512
)

input_ids = inputs['input_ids'].to('mps')
attention_mask = inputs['attention_mask'].to('mps')

dataloader = DataLoader(
    list(zip(input_ids, attention_mask)),
    batch_size=2,
    shuffle=False
)

def calculate_perplexity(model, dataloader):
    model.eval()
    total_loss = 0
    num_batches = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for batch in dataloader:
            input_ids, attention_mask = batch
            outputs = model(input_ids=input_ids, attention_mask=attention_mask, labels=input_ids)
            loss = outputs.loss
            total_loss += loss.item()
            num_batches += 1
    avg_loss = total_loss / num_batches 
    perplexity = math.exp(avg_loss)
    return perplexity


gpt2_perplexity = calculate_perplexity(gpt2_model, dataloader)
print(f"GPT-2 XL Perplexity on WikiText-2: {gpt2_perplexity}")

Is there something wrong with my code? tokenization?
Thanks
